# delay stateChangeStart until it finishes an ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to check on state changes whether user is logged and I'm trying to restore the logged state with a token from the cookies when he is not

```
eFx.run(function($rootScope, $cookieStore, $location, Auth) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event) {
    if ($rootScope.user == null) {
      if ($cookieStore.get('token') != undefined) {
        Auth.logIn({'token': $cookieStore.get('token')}).then(function(data) {
          $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
          $rootScope.user = data.user;
          $rootScope.token = data.token;
        }, function(data) {
          $location.path("/login");
        });
      }
      else {
        $location.path("/login");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The problem that I'm having is my page controller gets initiated and calls an ajax with a token that is trying to get from the `$rootScope` before this Auth ajax inside the stateChangeStart returns the promise.

Is there a way to make this block of code so it loads the page only after it returned the ajax promise?
Thank you in advance, Daniel.

Comment: Use router resolve... and make the ajax call there and return its promise. Route will render only if the promise is resolved it it is rejected it wont

Comment: You can use $timeout in controller to queue your work to be run after current digest cycle (also waits for DOM rendering to be completed by the browser).